# HTML onclick argument

Tags: html

I would like to know what the return false statement does in this excerpt of HTML code. I don't understand why it isn't just the submit call. I would especially like to know WHERE false is being returned to. The excerpt is from:

http://www.autozone.com/autozone/storelocator/storeLocatorMain.jsp

```
<\a class="actionButton orange"
    onclick="document.storeLocatorForm.submit();return false;">
 <\span>SUBMIT<\/span>
<\/a>
```

I know it must have a simple answer but I haven't had much success googling it. I always get people asking much more complicated questions. I took the HTML and JavaScript tutorial at w3schools but it's been a while so I don't really remember how this fits in.

Comment: `return false` in the context of a form `submit` handler will cancel the form submission before it is sent wherever it is meant to go.

Comment: Also, your markup is not exactly making sense (elements typically don't have <\ to start off with).

Comment: Yeah I know. When I copied and pasted it in I was in a hurry and I don't really know how to cancel it from interpreting the HTML in the post. Originally it just displayed SUBMIT. I added the slashes as a make-shift way to cancel the automatic interpretation of the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning false in an event handler prevents the event from triggering the "default behavior" of the underlying control.

It's common to see this on links:

```
<a href='/something/useful' onClick='jsMagic();return false;'>
  link text
</a>
```

The on-click executes your function and then also prevents the user from navigating to `/something/useful`.

Comment: Is it really common to see that? Why wouldn't `jsMagic()` just return false?

Comment: If `jsMagic()` returned false, my example would have to be longer to illustrate the idea.

Comment: That makes sense, but do you know why they might include that return false if there was no href value set?

Answer (score 0):

There is a form somewhere on the page called StoreLocatorForm. When the link is clicked, it submits the form data and processes it however the function is programed to.

THe return:false; part is to keep it from not submitting before you actually click the link.